# How to improve Kannel SMS Gateway - sending SMS messages is slow

Tags: modem, sms-gateway, kannel

I'm using kannel as an SMS Gateway to send SMS messages. I've downloaded kannel 1.4.3 and I use a Siemens TC35i as a GSM Modem. I can send messages by calling **http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=*username*&password=*password*&to=*recipient*&text=*message***

However, if I atempt to send 100 messages to the same recipient, it is a bit slow (it takes about 10 minutes to send 100 messages to the same recipient), i.e. 1 sms / 6 seconds.

Is there any way to improve the rate?

Here is my smskannel.conf file

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = bar
log-file = "/tmp/kannel.log"
log-level = 0
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"
access-log = "/tmp/access.log"


group = smsc
smsc = at
modemtype = auto
device=/dev/ttyUSB0
my-number = 0040728467060
connect-allow-ip = 127.0.0.1
log-level = 0
speed = 115200


group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = 0040728467060
log-file = "/tmp/smsbox.log"
log-level = 0
access-log = "/tmp/access.log"


group = sendsms-user
username = tester
password = foobar
concatenation = true
max-messages = 10000


group = sms-service
keyword = default
concatenation = true
catch-all = yes
max-messages = 10000
get-url = "http://localhost/sms?phone=%p&text=%a"

# There should be always a 'default' service. This service is used when no
# other 'sms-service' is applied.

group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "No service specified"
max-messages = 1

include = "/etc/kannel/modems.conf"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GSM protocol takes 6 seconds to process one SMS sending (standard by protocol). You are using GSM modem, so you cannot gain more speed than this. If you need a faster connection, get an IP connection from the operator.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your configuration, since you've not set any throughput limit, the only guess is that the mobile operator you're using is limiting message sending to about 1 sms per 6 second. There is nothing in your configuration that would limit you in such a way.

Comment: I've got the GSM Modem connected to my laptop via an USB - RS-232 adapter. Is it possible that the transmission rate via USB is limited? 


Also, is it possible that the Siemens TC35i modem I'm using has any sort of limitation when sending messages?

Comment: **later edit:** I've asked the mobile operator and it said they don't have any kind of limitation on their network, and any limitation may be due to my phone (in this case, my hardware: GSM Modem, USB Adapter, etc).

What kind of GSM Modems has any of you used that could send sms messages at an acceptable rate?

Comment: GSM modem is a low-volume solution. It doesn't scale up, so don't expect to speed up it significantly, if possible at all. Depending on your needs you may either put several modems to work in parallel or contact your operator and request services like sms via custom http protocol (probably easiest) or access to smpp gateway (Kannel can handle it).